# Why does the add_image_size() function not create a copy of the thumbnail image in wordpress?

Tags: image, wordpress, thumbnails

I have uploaded a photo in WordPress. I am trying to post a thumbnail of the image using a predetermined width while constraining the height proportionally.

**In functions.js:**

```
add_image_size('width-130', 130, 0, false);
```

**On the page that outputs the thumbnail:**

```
the_post_thumbnail('width-130');
```

According to the WordPress docs(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size), it says:

> WordPress will create a copy of the post thumbnail with the specified
>   dimensions when you upload a new thumbnail.

Currently it is outputting the full thumbnail image with a width attribute of 130. This still requires the full size image to load, which is not what I want. I would like for WordPress to create an actual copy of the post thumbnail with the correct dimensions, and not just to set the width attribute. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered my mistake.

Since I had not re-uploaded the image file, it was still trying to access the full size image which was the assigned image for that post, while adding the width attribute. Once I re-uploaded the image, the add_image_size() function is now actually creating a copy of the thumbnail with the correct dimensions.

I apologize for asking this question. If the community wants, I can close it but I figure it might be good reference for WordPress newbies such as myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin to regenerate thumbnails.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs across a similar problem, this may help. add_image_size generates derivatives that are smaller, but not bigger or the same size. Thus if you are trying to make a monochrome derivative image, uploading an image the same size as the monochrome, it will not be available and [techniques like this one won't work](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51603/how-to-add-multiple-image-sizes-of-the-same-size-with-add-image-size).